# Adding leading zero to value less than 1

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

Given a decimal value, how can I add a leading zero in a string *only* when a value is less than 1?

Eg.

```
.20  ->  "0.20"   - Add a leading 0

1.20 ->  "1.20"   - Value remains the same
```

The value before the decimal place could be of any length and the value after the decimal place will only be 2 digits ie. currency. Is this achievable with String.Format()? Or should I rely on a basic if statement?

The String.Format() documentation is rather confusing to me.

I've checked several other questions/answers and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

EDIT: As mentioned by several answers, this kind of leading zero addition should be the default behavior of the ToString() method called on a value. For whatever reason, that isn't happening in my case, so The String.Format() is necessary in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible with string.format():

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 0.2)  // 0.20
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 1.20) // 1.20
```

You can also use ToString() on the variables themselves:

```
var d1 = 0.2;
var d2 = 1.20;
Console.WriteLine(d1.ToString("0.00"));  // 0.20
Console.WriteLine(d2.ToString("0.00"));  // 1.20
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use zero before a dot in the format string, you would get the desired effect:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", currency);
```

or using C# 6 syntax

```
$"{currency:0.00}"
```

Note that .NET also provides a generic format specifier for formatting currency, which takes care of leading zero as well:

```
$"{currency:C}"
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is actually the default behavior of `ToString()` for a decimal type. You dont need `String.Format()`.

```
    decimal d = .20M;
    string s = d.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Not sure why, but ToString() was giving me ".20", which is why I wanted to look for another way.

Comment: What data type are you using for your number?

Comment: The data type is `decimal`

Comment: Strange, I know. I've tried multiple online C# test environments and they give me "0.20", but for whatever reason, my program is shooting ".20" at me.

Comment: Ah it must be a culture related. My `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is en-US

Answer (score 1):

All the other prior answers would be the preferred way to do what you're attempting. But here is an alternative to using string format specifiers.

```
var valStrVersion = ((val < 1.0M) ? "0" + val.ToString() : val.ToString());
```

And then you could whatever it is you need to do with it. Convert it back, print it out, whatever. Are you appending M to your decimal value when you declare it? `decimal dec = 0.15M;`?